# How to use python pandas to get intersection of sets from a csv file

Tags: python, d3.js, pandas

I have a csv file which has 4 columns in it and 1200 rows.

The values in rows are either 1,0.

The 4 columns = setA, setB, setC, setD

I need to find all the possible
 `n(setA==1), n(setB==1), n(setC==1), n(setD==1), n(setA==1 ∩ setB==1), n(setA==1 ∩ setB==1 ∩ setC==1) .......`

Presently Im using this, but its painful,time consuming and confusing :

```
csv_pd[(csv_pd.setA==1) & (csv_pd.setB==0) & (csv_pd.setC==0)].groupby(csv_pd.D).count()
```

which is basically finding n(setA ∩ setD)

Is there a better one liner which could dump all the data I need properly without being so cumbersome.

I need all this data because Im generating a venn diagram for these sets based on http://benfred.github.io/venn.js/examples/intersection_tooltip.html , https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding a one-liner will improve readability, making it a little less confusing:

```
mask = (csv_pd.setA==1) & (csv_pd.setB==0) & (csv_pd.setC==0)
csv_pd[mask].groupby('D').count()
```

Another possibility, which  happens to be a one-liner, is to use [the `query` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
csv_pd.query('setA==1 & setB==0 & setC==0').groupby('D').count()
```

---

Note also that you can pass a column name to `groupby`, instead of Series values. Thus, `groupby('D')` instead of `groupby(csv_pd.D)`.

---

To count the size of all possible subsets, the [`powerset` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) would be helpful:

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def powerset(iterable, reverse=False, rvals=None):
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"""
    s = list(iterable)
    N = len(s)
    if rvals is None:
        rvals = range(N, -1, -1) if reverse else range(N + 1)
    return IT.chain.from_iterable(
        IT.combinations(s, r) for r in rvals)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df)
for cols in powerset(df.columns):
    if not cols: continue
    for vals in IT.product([0,1], repeat=len(cols)):
        mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df[c]==v for c, v in zip(cols, vals)])
        cond = ' & '.join(['{}={}'.format(c,v) for c, v in zip(cols,vals)])
        n = len(df[mask])
        print('n({}) = {}'.format(cond, n))
```

yields

```
n(A=0) = 8
n(A=1) = 2
n(B=0) = 4
n(B=1) = 6
...
n(A=0 & B=0) = 4
n(A=0 & B=1) = 4
n(A=1 & B=0) = 0
...
n(A=1 & B=1 & C=0 & D=0) = 0
n(A=1 & B=1 & C=0 & D=1) = 1
n(A=1 & B=1 & C=1 & D=0) = 0
n(A=1 & B=1 & C=1 & D=1) = 1
```